# Change screen while function runs then change back

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state-management

I'm trying to change the screen when a submit button is pressed.  The page is essentially just a spinner page.  I want it to change to the page while the data is submittied to the database, then change back once the database stuff is finished.

I can get the screen to change but can't get it to change back.  Well, I did once, but as soon as I started adding code to the functions it stopped working entirely.

I have a main homepage that has a table component

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: false
    };
  }

  handleSpinner() {
    this.setState({ loading: !this.state.loading })
  }

  handleCancel() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to clear the table?')) {
      this.setState({ data: [] })
    } else {
      return
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.loading ? <WaitingSpinner /> :
        <div>
          <MainTable data={this.state.data} handleCancel={this.handleCancel} handleSpinner={this.handleSpinner} />
        </div>
    );
  }
```

The table has a submit button that calls a submit handler.

```
  handleSubmit() {
    this.props.handleSpinner()
    this.writeToDatabase(this.props.data)
    this.props.handleSpinner()
  }

  async writeToDatabase(data) {
    await data.map(test => {
      console.log('DATA ', test)
      axios.post(`database stuff')
        .then(function (response) { console.log(response) }).catch(function (error) { console.log('Err ', error) })
    })
  }
```

My goal here is to change to the spinner, run the database function, once that completes it changes back.

At this point it changes to the spinner screen but never changes back to the main table page.  I'm guessing it has something to do with when the state actually gets updated but I don't know enough about it to track down what is going on.

Comment: `this.writeToDatabase` returns as soon as it is called which means that you're calling `this.props.handleSpinner()` in quick succession and that means that `this.state.loading` can be `false` the second time this function is called (the first call hasn't changed the state yet).

Comment: Declare `handleSubmit` as `async` and `await` `this.writeToDatabase`

Comment: This is getting so confusing...  I made the changes you suggested but now the screen isn't changing at all.  I am logging out the state value and I can see it changing, just no screen update.

Comment: Try: `this.setState(prevState => ({ loading: !prevState.loading }))`

Comment: That isn't working either.  :(